# Haskell - Couldn't match expected type. Help me understand the issue

Tags: haskell

I have the following type class instances:

```
type Scalar = Double
data Vector = Vector [Double] deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num Vector where
  (+) (Vector xs) (Vector ys) = Vector (zipWith (+) xs ys)
  (-) (Vector xs) (Vector ys) = Vector (zipWith (-) xs ys)
  (*) (Vector xs) (Vector ys) = Vector (zipWith (*) xs ys)

instance Fractional Vector where
  (/) (Vector xs) (Vector ys) = Vector (zipWith (/) xs ys)

dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
dot (Vector v1) (Vector v2) = sum $ v1 + v2
```

Yet the dot method does not type check. I guess it can't use the + method, even though it's on the Vector class.

```
 No instance for (Num [Double])
      arising from a use of `+'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Double])
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `v1 + v2'
    In the expression: sum $ v1 + v2
    In an equation for `dot':
        dot (Vector v1) (Vector v2) = sum $ v1 + v2
```

Edit: Well that was embarassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Mathematically, we usually don't define multiplication (or division) on vectors like that - we use the [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) or the dot product to combine two vectors.)*

Anyway, we *can* use your instance functions to define the dot product if you like:

```
dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Scalar
dot vector1 vector2 = let (Vector list3) = vector1 * vector2 in
   sum list3
```

Notice the type `Vector -> Vector -> Scalar`. The result type is `Scalar` because when you sum the multiplied entries, there's only one number, not a vector full of numbers. It also means that the two arguments `vector1` and `vector2` are Vectors, so they're written as `Vector somelist`.

We used `*` on `vector1` and `vector2` which have their `Vector` constructor still intact, because we can't multiply lists of Doubles. In your original code you tried to add (or multiply) lists of Doubles, which won't work, because your instance only defines addition and multiplication on Vectors, not raw [Double]s.

In the `let` clause, I've taken the result of this multiplication and matched it with `Vector list3`. That means that `list3` *is* a list of Doubles, so I can use the `sum` function on it; `sum` is defined on lists of Doubles but not on vectors, so using `sum` directly on `vector1 * vector2` wouldn't have worked.

Example:

```
> dot (Vector [1, 10, 100]) (Vector [1, 2, 3])
321.0
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the `sum` works in yours function (where you go `sum v3`, where `v3` is a `Vector`), yet I am unable to call sum on a Vector like so: `sum (Vector [3 3 3])`

Comment: `v3` is not a vector, it's a `[Double]` since it was unpacked from a `Vector`.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra I've expanded the explanation a bit and renamed the variables to provide type hints so now I've called `v3` `list3` instead - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in

```
dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
dot (Vector v1) (Vector v2) = sum $ v1 + v2
```

has the wrong type, instead you want

```
dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Double
dot (Vector v1) (Vector v2) = sum $ zipWith (*) v1 v2
```

note also that I changed the `+` to a `*` as I assume you want the dot product, alternatively

```
dot :: Vector -> Vector -> Double
dot v1 v2 = let Vector ls = v1 * v2 in sum ls
```

which uses the `Num` instance for `Vector`

Comment: Oh shit. How did I miss that. I changed it when debugging earlier and never changed it back.

Comment: Why can I not use the instance + functions I defined? I can in the repl. None of those definitions work.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra I don't know, the code I posted works for me